# pattern matching in ML for something other than int

Tags: pattern-matching, ml

I have this function in ML:

```
fun repeat(x,n:int)=
        if n<=0 then []
        else x::repeat(x,n-1)
    |repeat (x,_)=[];
```

now, I need the second repeat in case the second argument (n) will be something other than int. but I get a "match redundant" error for it. can someone explain please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ML is a typed language. Your explicit type annotation determines that the second argument of the function has type `int` (which actually is already determined implicitly by its comparison to 0, so the annotation is redundant). So obviously, there cannot be anything other than an integer to match, and the type system knows it.

(Edit: Stylistic note: better throw an exception (e.g. the predefined `Domain`) in case that `n < 0`, rather than silently returning a random default result.)

Comment: appreciate the answer. about the exception, this is part of a homework assignment so I don't decide on the requirements. but another question, is there a way to send different types to one function? if I want for example to do different things if 'n' is string or int?

Comment: No, nor should there be. For that, you have algebraic datatypes (disjoint unions), which you will probably get to at some point in the class.

Comment: yeah, we saw datatypes a couple of lessons ago, it's just not included in this specific assignment. thanx again